# Pipe input to suspended process

Tags: linux, command-line, piping, suspend

I'm trying to pipe some input(as in standard input, not a command-line argument) from a file into a suspended process on a linux machine, e.g,

```
cat file > fg
```

However, I can't seem to find the right command for this. So far I've tried

```
file > fg
file | fg
file - | fg
fg < file
fg < cat file
```

I know at least one of these would work when starting a new process but I specifically need to do this with a suspended process. Is there a command sequence specifically for what I'm looking for?

Alternatively, I could also pipe in the input using python -c print, but I haven't had success with this either.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this isn't possible to do. By the time the process is suspended, it already has its `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` file descriptors opened. For what you're wanting, `bash` would need some way of forcibly closing the `stdin` of the suspended process and then re-opening it with a new input fd. I would be very surprised if there was any way of doing this that didn't involve some very tricky code (eg. creating a thread inside the suspended process, suspending the main thread, using the new thread to close and re-open the `stdin` file descriptor). I would not expect such a process to complete properly with any amount of regularity.

But, I may also be very mistaken.